# display every other item on axis

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, linegraph

Google line chart displaying temperature hour for hour. Is it possible to just display every other hour on the x-axis. I could just set every second string to `empty`, but then one wouldn't be able to display it when hovering over the graph.

Maybe you could do something here?:

```
var options = {
 hAxis: {
 format: ''
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following option...

`showTextEvery` - How many horizontal axis labels to show, where 1 means show every label, 2 means show every other label, and so on. Default is to try to show as many labels as possible without overlapping.

```
var options = {
  hAxis: {
    showTextEvery: 2
  }
}
```

Comment: hope this helps, see [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) for more...